# Can't get rid of `$scope` in favor of `this` inside `$http.get` request

Tags: angularjs

**EDIT2:**

```
var LanguageCtrl;

LanguageCtrl = function($scope, $http, $window) {
  var vm;
  vm = this;
  if ($window.navigator.language.indexOf('it') !== -1) {
    this.lang = 'it';
    this.setLanguage = 'it';
  } else {
    this.lang = 'en';
    this.setLanguage = 'us';
  }
  this.message = [];
  this.pizze = [];
  this.getPizze = function(lang) {
    $http.get('localization/pizze-' + lang + '.json').success(function(pizze) {
      vm.pizze = pizze;
    });
  };
  this.setLanguage = function(lang) {
    $http.get('localization/' + lang + '.json').success(function(data) {
      vm.lang = lang;
      vm.message = data;
      vm.getPizze(vm.lang);
      $window.location.href = '#!/order';
    });
  };
  this.setLanguage(this.lang);
};

angular.module('myApp').controller('LanguageCtrl', LanguageCtrl);
```

---

**EDIT:** what I said doesn't work, doesn't work when I use `this` rather than `$scope`!

I'm moving to the `controller as` syntax and everything's fine when I do this for variables, but when I try the same thing for arrays populated by an `$http.get`, the code breaks.

*Don't care about that horrible `<button onclick>`, just wanted to test code postponing the style for links.*

controller

```
var LanguageCtrl;

LanguageCtrl = function($scope, $http, $window) {
  if ($window.navigator.language.indexOf('it') !== -1) {
    this.lang = 'it';
    this.setLanguage = 'it';
  } else {
    this.lang = 'en';
    this.setLanguage = 'us';
  }
  this.message = [];
  this.pizze = [];
  $scope.getPizze = function(lang) {
    $http.get('localization/pizze-' + lang + '.json').success(function(pizze) {
      $scope.pizze = pizze;
    });
  };
  $scope.setLanguage = function(lang) {
    $http.get('localization/' + lang + '.json').success(function(data) {
      this.lang = lang;
      $scope.message = data;
      $scope.getPizze(this.lang);
      $window.location.href = '#!/order';
    });
  };
  $scope.setLanguage(this.lang);
};

angular.module('myApp').controller('LanguageCtrl', LanguageCtrl);
```

index.html works

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LanguageCtrl as langctrl" lang="{{langctrl.lang}}">
```

order.html doesn't

```
<button onclick="location.href='#!/cart'" ng-disabled="howManyPizze === 0">{{langctrl.message.cart}} {{howManyPizze === 0 ? langctrl.message.empty : '(' + howManyPizze + ')'}}</button>
<button onclick="location.href='#!/'">{{langctrl.message.change}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the self-referencing `this` is not available when your `$http.get()` resolves. That is why you'll often see `var vm = this;` or something similar as the very first line in a controller when using the 'Controller as' syntax. By assigning `this` to a local variable in the controller it gives you access when your promise resolves. In short, add...

```
var vm = this;
```

...to your controller and then change your `$http.get()` to this...

```
vm.setLanguage = function(lang) {
    $http.get('localization/' + lang + '.json').success(function(data) {
        vm.lang = lang;
        vm.message = data;
        vm.getPizze(vm.lang);
        $window.location.href = '#!/order';
    });
};
```

**UPDATE**
I missed this on my original answer:

```
$scope.getPizze = function(lang) {
    $http.get('localization/pizze-' + lang + '.json').success(function(pizze) {
        $scope.pizze = pizze;
    });
};
```

That needs to be changed to eliminate the use of `$scope`.

```
vm.getPizze = function(lang) {
    $http.get('localization/pizze-' + lang + '.json').success(function(pizze) {
        vm.pizze = pizze;
    });
};
```

Comment: `message` works but it seems I can't call `getPizze`. Question updated with your suggestion, what did I done bad?

Comment: That was my bad - I missed that you were still using `$scope` when adding that function to your controller. My answer has been updated.

Comment: I would actually recommend that after using `var vm = this;` you just use `vm` in place of `this` everywhere. It looks odd to be mixing the two and perhaps it will help to make it more clear in your code to use a single identifier.

Comment: I've had already changed it (in fact it's in my edit2), but my ngRepeat wasn't working... then I remembered the "Controller as" syntax and everything was fine :D thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var LanguageCtrl;

LanguageCtrl = function( $http, $window) {
  var parent = this;
  if ($window.navigator.language.indexOf('it') !== -1) {
   parent.lang = 'it';
   parent.setLanguage = 'it';
 } else {
   parent.lang = 'en';
   parent.setLanguage = 'us';
 }
 this.message = [];
 this.pizze = [];
 parent.getPizze = function(lang) {
   $http.get('localization/pizze-' + lang + '.json').success(function(pizze)    {
     console.log("Your language is:"+lang)
     parent.pizze = pizze;
   });
 };
 parent.setLanguage = function(lang) {
   $http.get("example.json").success(function(data) {
    // $scope.$apply(function(){
     console.log("Your language is:"+lang)
     parent.lang = lang;
     parent.message = data;
     parent.getPizze(parent.lang);
     $window.location.href = '#!/order';     
    //})

  });
 };
 parent.setLanguage(parent.lang);
};
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('LanguageCtrl', LanguageCtrl);
```

Use above code to work your angular code.

Created Plukar here https://plnkr.co/edit/psOaylBtnCsLDIJydT9N?p=preview

Comment: Uhm maybe I've written bad my question. How can I swap from `$scope` to `this`?

Comment: `ReferenceError: lang is not defined`

Comment: But maybe I'm not explained myself, or maybe I didn't understand you. Is this a case when I cannot use `this` rather than `$scope`? Because if I remove langctrl from message.value my code works

Comment: Updated. Please confirm its working or not. I used example.json file to serve it. You can use your own.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I was asking how to get rid of `$scope`, like in the other answer

Comment: Replace **parent** with **$scope** and remove **$scope** from your controller injection. See updated Plunker.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly this way like it was suggested in the other answer :) thank you!